# nginx rewrite url in the proxy page

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, proxy

I have some trouble with a page that is running trough a nginx proxy.
This page does calls other internal servers and I would like to rewrite these URLs with nginx.

I already have a proxy pass running for the following:

foo.site.internal --> foo.site.nl (public)
The site internal, calls for some other services like:
foo2.site.internal:1400/json/api/call/bla

Currently foo.site.nl is trying to receive those calls by some javescript usage. But this is not possible because the end user can't connect to foo2.site.internal

So I have created a reverse proxy for:
foo2.site.internal:1400 that is running at: foo.site.nl:1400, so what I would like to accomplish without changing the config of the backend site is this:

rewrite foo2.site.internal:1400/json/api/call/bla in page to foo.site.nl:1400/json/api/call/bla

Could such a thing be possible with nginx?

My current config:

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/site.nl.cert;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/site.nl.key;

  server_name foo.site.nl;

  location / {
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://foo.site.internal/;
  }
}

server {
  listen      14000 default_server;
  server_name foo.site.nl;
  location / {
    proxy_pass       http://foo2.site.internal:14000;
    proxy_set_header Host foo2.site.internal:14000;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this configuration :

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/site.nl.cert;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/site.nl.key;

  server_name foo.site.nl;

  location / {
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://foo.site.internal/;
  }
}

server {
  listen      14000 default_server;
  server_name foo.site.nl;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    proxy_pass       http://foo2.site.internal:14000;
    proxy_set_header Host foo2.site.internal:14000;
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work: https://s21.postimg.org/hr9v8m5fb/imagekopie.png
I would like to rewrite the URL in content of de webpage.
And the https error will be solved when the page's urls are rewritten to intra-intern.domain.nl(public page)